# Как задать точку вращения transform-origin относительно центра элемента?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию иконки раскрывающегося меню
,чтобы три горизонтальные черты превращались в Х, пробовал разные варианты с параметрами display и position но все равно не получается нормально центрировать элементы, в чем моя ошибка?

```js
$("#icon").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggleClass("menuafter");
  $(".line").toggleClass("lineafter");
  $(".line1").toggleClass("line1after");
  $(".line2").toggleClass("line2after");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  align-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

#icon {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 999;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s, scale ease-in-out .5s;
}

.line,
.line1,
.line2 {
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.lineafter {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateY(7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
}

.line1after {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
}

.line2after {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateY(-7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s
}

#icon:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s, scale ease-in-out .5s;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  right: 0;
  background: coral;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: width ease .5s, font-size ease .5s;
}

.menuafter {
  display: inline-flex;
  right: 0;
  background: coral;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: width ease .5s, font-size ease .5s;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="left">


  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <input id="menu1" type="checkbox" name="menu">
    <label id="icon" for="menu1">
 <div class="line">
 </div>
 <div class="line1">
 </div>
 <div class="line2">
 </div>
</label>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <p>MENU <br>MENU</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#icon").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggleClass("menuafter");
  $(".line").toggleClass("lineafter");
  $(".line1").toggleClass("line1after");
  $(".line2").toggleClass("line2after");
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  background: #d7d7d7;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: silver;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  align-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: gray;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

#icon {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 999;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s, scale ease-in-out .5s;
}

.line,
.line1,
.line2 {
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.lineafter {
/*   position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateY(7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s; */
}

.line1after {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
}

.line2after {
  position: absolute;
  background: gray;
  height: 4px;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 1.5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transform: translateY(-7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s
}

#icon:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
  transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s, scale ease-in-out .5s;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  right: 0;
  background: coral;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: width ease .5s, font-size ease .5s;
}

.menuafter {
  display: inline-flex;
  right: 0;
  background: coral;
  opacity: .5;
  position: absolute;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: width ease .5s, font-size ease .5s;
}

input {
  display: none;
}
.line::after, .line::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.line::after {
  bottom: -6px;
}
.line::before {
  top: -6px;
}
.line.lineafter {
  background: transparent;
}
.line.lineafter::before {
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Для Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Для IE */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Для Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
}
.line.lineafter::after {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Для Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Для IE */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Для Safari, Chrome, iOS */
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Для Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="left">


  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <input id="menu1" type="checkbox" name="menu">
    <label id="icon" for="menu1">
 <div class="line">
 </div>
</label>
    <div id="menu" class="menu">
      <p>MENU <br>MENU</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```